# Dynamic JSON structure

Tags: json, dynamic, key

I am trying to make a JSON-key dynamic with the following data and function:

```
var jsonData = [ ];

                addProcess("Text1", "Text2", jsonData)
                function addProcessingPurpose(title, domain, arr) {

                    arr.push({
                        "First": title,
                        domain : {
                            "subitem": {
                                "Subsubitem": "text"
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

I get the desired output expect I don't seem to manage setting the keys dynamically from the function parameter. E.g. now it prints "domain" instead of "Text2" which is my desired output. How can this be solved please?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the stupid question, solved it myself didn't saw I forgot the [ ] around the key.. Thank you anyway, maybe it can help someone else..